# How can I set the design preview in Android Studio to show a tablet layout instead of a phone layout?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm at the moment developing an app for tablets and the app isn't supposed to be available for phones.
When I edit an XML in Android Studio, there's the design preview that shows roughly how the XML will be rendered on the device. By default it's set to show it in a phone device. How do I set this to be a tablet view?

Comment: You can change the device layout in that xml editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, it should have a nexus 5 and an icon at the top. Click on that icon ans a list of devices will appear.In the third listView you will find Nexus 7 where it is a tablet. CHoose one from that listView.[image]

Answer (score 2):

Go to **XML EDITOR**

Click on **Device** Editor

Now you will see different type of Device with there **Name** ,**resolution** and **size**

Bottom of the device list you will see **Generic Phones and Tablets**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In Android Studio, go to `Preview - Top Toolbar`:

[image]

- The pixel phone name will let you choose the screen to show in the
  Android Studio Preview so, this can be helpful to design the layout
  for Tablets.
- The second icon, has two options called `Landscape` and `portrait` which the first one `Landscape` will help to design the layout for the purpose.
- The second option & important is, `Create Tablet Variation` which creates few directories for designing the Tablet layout.

---

There is also an option in the phone icon called `Generic phones and Tablets` which you might consider using.